# Java Programming and Garbage Collection

Tags: java, class, object

This is a question I have from Lecture about the discussion of Garbage Collection. I cannot figure which line cause the garbage collection.

I have tried using the compiler to run the programming and the outputs are

```
#1: [C001, C002]
#2: [C001, C002, C001]
#3: [C001, C002, C001]
```

I know that there is a line that cause Garbage Collection but I cannot figure it out. At the same time, professor required us to draw a diagram showing how the objects and data, lists go.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Customer a = new Customer("C001");
        Customer b = new Customer("C002");

        ArrayList<Customer> list1 = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        list1.add(a);
        list1.add(b);
        System.out.println("#1: " + list1.toString()); Icdddd

        ArrayList<Customer> list2 = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        list2 = list1;
        list2.add(a);
        System.out.println("#2: " + list1.toString()); 
        System.out.println("#3: " + list2.toString()); 
    }

}
```

Comment: you can not trigger garbage collection. you can only kindly ask the garbe colletion to run (`System.gc()`).

Comment: @ Philipp Sander I asked and found there are no.....

Answer (score 3):

There is no line that causes Garbage Collection, because garbage collection is not something that you as a programmer can trigger. However, after `list2 = list1;` the `ArrayList` reference created by `ArrayList<Customer> list2 = new ArrayList<Customer>();` is ***eligible*** for garbage collection.

Comment: I understand and agree to your point! However, the lecturer asked us to tell her which is the line cause garbage collection.

Comment: Maybe debugging the lecturer might give an explanation

Comment: I'm afraid this is the only answer in Java, perhaps follow-up with her. It might also be worth asking your lecturer why they chose to use `ArrayList<Customer> list1 = new ArrayList<Customer>();` instead of using the diamond operator `ArrayList<Customer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();` (Java 7 came out in 2011).

Comment: ArrayList<Customer> list2 = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        As mentioned by Elliott, line above creates a new object which becomes eligible for garbage collection as soon as you do list2=list1

Comment: Chances are that each List.toString() call returns a temporary String, which is collectable after it's concatenated to the literal prefix to make a new temporary String as argument to println, which in turn becomes collectable after println returns.

Comment: @another-dave That is true, but this code will almost certainly complete and terminate before garbage collection runs.

Answer (score 0):

so finally the professor said the answer is list2 = list1; which cause the garbage collection, whereas line 7 is redundant

Comment: You *might* want to ask your professor to explain the purpose of [`Runtime.gc()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#gc--); and also what the word "suggests" means in *Calling this method suggests that the Java virtual machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory they currently occupy available for quick reuse.* The reality is that such a short program with no obvious memory constraints is highly unlikely to trigger garbage collection during its' runtime. Computers with 32mb of RAM ran garbage collection a lot, you have more.